# Polynomial of degree N with integer coefficient for a given root.

Tags: polynomials, computer-algebra

Is it possible to construct a polynomial of degree `N`, with all of them as integer coefficient have a `root` as the given value. The root value provided is not necessarily a rational number.

For example, if the root is `28.552622898861801` we can have a polynomial of degree 10 whose one root will be the given value.

`10000 x^10 - 280000 x^9 - 150000 x^8 - 220000 x^7 - 40000 x^6 - 790000 x^5 - 160000 x^4 - 320000 x^3 - 270000 x^2 - 250000 x - 251271 = 0`

[Wolfram alpha link for this equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000+x%5E10+-+280000+x%5E9+-+150000+x%5E8+-+220000+x%5E7+-+40000+x%5E6+-+790000+x%5E5+-+160000+x%5E4+-+320000+x%5E3+-+270000+x%5E2+-+250000+x+-+251271+%253D+0)

Comment: If your rational number is $p/q$ you can take the polynomial $(px-q)^N$. Or did I misunderstand the question.

Comment: I meant $(qx-p)^N$.


Comment: oops. updated the description.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number. Not all real numbers are algebraic.

Comment: Although weaker, there are only countably many (finite degree with one variable) polynomials with integer coefficients that are somewhere nonzero, giving only countably many complex numbers that could be roots of one of these polynomials.  This is essentially Georg Cantor's existence proof of transcendental numbers.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.20

Comment: Your welcome. For the future you might want to try asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead of this site which is more for research level questions.

Comment: Random comment: It's fascinating how math students who haven't yet reached the research level will often ask questions that potentially lead them to an entirely new area of math, entirely by their own accord. In this case, the study of transcendental numbers. There are certainly better examples than this one (for example, a doctor who got lots of citations on a published paper that re-invented trapezoidal rule).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by running some Integer Relation algorithm (e.g., PSLQ) on the numbers $1, r, r^2, \dots, r^N$ where $r$ is a given root.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm

For example, here is computation in PARI/GP which gives a better result than the polynomial shown in question:

? r = 28.552622898861801; algdep(r,10)

%1 = 3*x^10 + 38*x^9 - 3695*x^8 + 4582*x^7 + 3016*x^6 + 1435*x^5 + 4552*x^4 - 1219*x^3 - 9920*x^2 - 2402*x + 3087

? subst(%1,x,r)

%2 = -2.7334689816478450022 E-24